# Why does boolean true have toJSON method in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, jquery-ui-widget

This is a weird IE quirk. Here are the steps:

1. Go to [msn.com](http://msn.com) in Internet Explorer 8
2. Pull up dev tools
3. Switch Browser Mode to "IE8 Compat View"
4. Switch Document Mode to "IE7 Standards"
5. Switch to Script tab
6. run the following script: `true.toJSON()`

it returns `true`. No other browser does this. It's giving me issues because it's causing the tooltip widget of jQueryUI to fail for IE because at some point it passes a boolean value of `true` to `$.isEmptyObject()`. Normally passing in `true` would just return `true` but since `true` now has a method associated with it (`toJSON`) it is returning `false` and breaking the widget.

I noticed there are some sites (like Google) that you can try to do the same test and `true.toJSON()` just breaks without returning anything. What is this weird `toJSON` method and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: You really need to support IE7?  Maybe you can try `delete true.toJSON`.  `true` is a boolean object

Comment: preumably this should be `delete Boolean.prototype.toJSON` - but that seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: This appears to be specific to [msn.com](http://www.msn.com/). Try another site and you'll find most don't have it. This mean MSN defined the method themselves by extending the [`Boolean.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/prototype).

Comment: It definitely occurs on other sites like USA.gov and the site I'm working on. I don't know why.

Comment: trying to delete it might be a good idea if it only occurs in one browser under certain settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `jQuery.isEmptyObject()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/):

> The argument should always be a plain JavaScript Object as other types
>   of object (DOM elements, primitive strings/numbers, host objects) may
>   not give consistent results across browsers.

In other words, fix the tooltip widget.

Comment: You're right. I logged a defect for the tooltip widget.
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9110

Comment: I  figured out that the reason for the JS error was caused by only using a subset of the jquery-ui code.

Answer (score 0):

`toJSON` is a method that, if defined on an object, specifies the way `JSON.stringify` works on it. Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON#toJSON%28%29_method) for more details.